# What does it mean for $\omega$ to not be "real" in practice?

Tags: plasma-physics, dissipation, non-equilibrium

I am reading about landau damping  and the author states that $\omega$ is never real (due to collisions).
https://cds.cern.ch/record/1982428/files/377-404%20Herr.pdf
\begin{equation}
1 + \frac{\omega_e^2}{k^2} \int \frac{\partial v_x g(v_x)}{\omega/k-v_x} dv_x = 0
\end{equation}

What exactly does it mean for omega to be complex valued?

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/135182/59023

Comment: The imaginary part of a frequency is conventionally taken as meaning the growth/damping rate with respect to the temporal dimension.  The imaginary part of the wavenumber, correspondingly, is taken as the growth/damping rate with respect to the spatial dimension.

Answer (score 2):

A complex frequency $\omega$ is related to dissipation. Is the idea that if your wave is described by $\mathbf A =\mathbf A_0 \exp(\mathrm i\omega t)$ as a function of time $t$, where $\mathbf A_0$ is an amplitude (vector if needed), then you can decompose it such that
$$\mathbf A=\mathbf A_0'(t) \exp[\mathrm i\Re(\omega) )t],$$
where $\Re$ is the real part, and
$$\mathbf A_0'(t)=\mathbf A_0\exp[-\mathrm \Im(\omega) t] ,$$
where $\Im$ is the imaginary part. The whole idea idea is that the wave now is described by a new amplitude $\mathbf A_0'(t)$ that decays exponentially with time (note the lack of imaginary $\mathrm i$).

Note: for this to work, you have to choose a convention, I choose here that the imaginary part of $\omega$ is always positive. The opposite convention exists too but you have to change the sign of the whole exponent.