# Tensor Formulation of Maxwell's Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations, duality

I've been reading up about the tensor formulation of Maxwell's Equations of Electromagnetism, and the derivations I have seen (found here: http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/lecture-2-3/maxwells-equations/) gives them in covariant form (*in vacuo*) as: 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu} &= &0 \\ \partial_{\mu}\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} & = & 0 \end{array}$$
Where $F^{\mu \nu}$ is the electromagnetic tensor and $\tilde{F}^{\mu \nu}$ is a modified electromagnetic tensor in which:
$$\begin{array}{rcl} E_m & \to & -B_m \\ B_m & \to & E_m \end{array}$$

I (just about) understand how these arose, however I'm sure I had previously seen them formulated as a single tensor equation (of a similar form): does anyone know how this looks/arises?

If possible could answers take a more component-based approach, as this is what I am able to work with easiest (don't worry if not though).

Comment: I have always seen them written with at least two equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Significance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to combine the two equations into one by defining the   Riemann-Silberstein field $\Psi= {\bf E}+i{\bf B}$.  Then the time dependent Maxwell equations become 
$$
i\partial_t \Psi   = -i (\Sigma_x  \partial_y+ \Sigma_y \partial_y+\Sigma_z  \partial_z)\Psi
$$
 where the $\Sigma_{x,y,z}$ are the spin-one version of the Pauli sigma matrices.  The resulting equation is  a spin-one version of the Weyl equation.  There are a number of subtleties here though, and these equations do not describe static solutions.  There is Wikipedia article on Riemann-Silberstein that contains the details.

Comment: More about the RS vector [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80039/26076)