# Complex-valued current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, complex-numbers

I'm reading in several places (e.g., [here](https://www.esi-group.com/sites/default/files/resource/publication/1660/inductionaxiieee97.pdf)), that

> the current density is supposed to be in the form $\mathbf{j}=j(r, z) \exp(i\omega t) \,\mathbf{e}_\varphi, [...]$

This implies that the current density has complex values, while I had been under the impression that it, as an observable quantity (the electric current per unit area), is always real-valued.

How to consolidate the two views?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80028/2451 ,  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44959/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related, and with essentially the same answer: [What is the physical significance of the imaginary part when plane waves are represented as $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316135/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current is real-valued like electromagnetic fields. The complex formalism is largely used in electromagnetism when you have to face oscillating quantities because it is easier to handle that *cosines / sines*.

You can do calculation using the complex notation and then take the real part of the expression to come back to the physical quantities.

In your case the current is  $\mathbf{j}=\Re( j(r, z) \exp(i\omega t))\,\mathbf{e}_\varphi$. Taking real part of a complex quantity in electromagnetism it is usually implicit.