# Why are the electromagnetic wave equation is represented in a complex number?

Tags: waves, complex-numbers

The wave function
$$
f(x,t) = A \sin (\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t+ \phi) 
$$

Can graphically describe the linear 2d wave propagation. Why this equations is written in this form:
$$
f(x,t) = A [\cos (\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x} - \omega t+ \phi) + i \sin (\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}- \omega t+ \phi)]
$$
which is eventually converted to
$$
f(x,t) = A e^{i \varphi(\vec{x},t)}
$$

What does the addition of the imaginary part add to the graphical representation of the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the need of complex functions in wave analysis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209069/)

Comment: It's not about graphical representation, it's the fact that the exponential obeys the same linear equations the real solution does, and it is easier to manipulate (differentiate, group, etc.) terms like $e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$ than terms like $e^{-k''z}\cos(k'z-\omega t)$ (both can describe decaying wave due to absorption).

Comment: My point as, why adding the term i sin (kx-ωt + ϕ) to the function when only the real part 
F(x,t) = A cos (kx-ωt + ϕ) would have perfectly sufficed the description of a linear sinusoidal wave function? Why must we add a redundant term i sin (kx-ωt + ϕ) just to fulfill the satisfaction of replacing this whole expression cos (kx-ωt + ϕ) +  i sin (kx-ωt + ϕ) with the euler identity  e^i(kx-ωt+ϕ)