# Is there an equivalent to the Schrodinger equation for quantum mechanics over the reals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers, time-evolution

Many people have considered alternatives to standard quantum mechanics in which the Hilbert space is over the real instead of the complex numbers - see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9905037), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0009063), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104088), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101012), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401062), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09029). In general, this alternate theory is surprisingly similar to standard quantum mechanics over the complex numbers:

> All the greatest hits are still there: interference, entanglement, Bell inequality violations, noncommuting observables, non-unique decompositions of mixed states, universal quantum computing, the Zeno effect, the Gleason and Kochen-Specker theorems.

But I'm not sure how one would generalize the Schrodinger equation to the real setting. In order to get a unitary time-evolution operator, you need to exponentiate an *anti*-Hermitian operator. The only operator conveniently lying around is the Hamiltonian, which is Hermitian. Fortunately, with the complex numbers there's an easy way to convert a Hermitian operator into an anti-Hermitian one: you just multiply it by $-i$, as is done in the Schrodinger equation. But with the real numbers, I can't think of any natural way to convert the symmetric Hamiltonian operator into an antisymmetric operator which exponentiates to an orthogonal time-evolution operator. How would this work?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32422/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292947/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8062/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think any of those are duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum mechanics for a real wave function $\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$ has the wave equation ("Schrödinger equation")
$$\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(\mathbf{r},t)=A\psi(\mathbf{r},t),$$
where $A$ is a real anti-Hermitian operator ("Hamiltonian"). A Majorana fermion on the 2D surface of a topological superconductor provides one realization, with a two-component spinor $\psi(x,y,t)$ and a $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian matrix $A$ with elements
$$A=v\begin{pmatrix}
\partial/\partial y&\partial/\partial x\\
\partial/\partial x&-\partial/\partial y
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
0&V(x,y)\\
-V(x,y)&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
(The coefficient $v$ is the energy-independent velocity of the Majorana fermions and $V$ is a spatially-dependent magnetisation.)

Comment: A remark - what is a real spinor? Spinors are defined on $\mathbb{C}$ AFAIK, real spinor is just a two component vector, which carries less information than complex spinor?

Comment: [Majorana spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Terminology_in_physics) are a real representation of the Clifford algebra

Answer (score 2):

If you have a symmetric operator $S$, you can turn it into an antisymmetric one by embedding it into a complex structure. For example, the analogue of multiplying the self-adjoint $H$ by $i$ would be the tensor product

$$J\otimes S$$

where $J$ is the symplectic form on $\mathbb R^2$. In the embedding, $S$ identifies with $I_2\otimes S$, where $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.

It shouldn't be a surprise that this embedding trick and the complex setting lead to about the same result. In both case you have doubled the number of real dimensions.

Comment: Fair point, but I'd argue that this trick violates the spirit of real-valued QM by essentially sneaking the complex structure in through the back door. In particular, the "antisymmetrized" operator acts on a different (larger) Hilbert space than the original one.