# Can we get rid of complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Complex number is very weird to me, especially so when they appear in engineering and physics equations.

It is possible to [represent complex number as real matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51292/relation-of-this-antisymmetric-matrix-r-left-beginsmallmatrix0-1-10-e) where 
$i = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $1= I$

However, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the $i$-matrix
 are complex. Which means complex numbers may reappear even if we use the matrix representation.

Is it possible to totally get rid of complex number from our real world equations? Or is it so fundamental in our world?

Comment: they are equivalent to R^2, so it is messy but you can

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11396/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You can't get rid of the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients doesn't always have $n$ real roots, but a polynomial with complex coefficients does always have $n$ complex roots. In other words, you *can* get rid of complex numbers, but doing that is a complicated and untidy mess compared with keeping them.

Comment: Re, "Complex number is very weird to me." That's the fault of your teachers. There are not many math _educators_ who know (or will take the time to explain) the practical applications of complex numbers. Start by learning how complex multiplication relates to _rotations_ in the complex plane. Then, learn what $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $e^x$ mean in the complex world. (Hint: They're all solutions to the same differential equation.) Complex math simplifies the analysis of periodic functions, and wave phenomena. If you need help, seek an engineer or a physicist, not a math teacher.

Comment: Actually, thinking complex&real number as matrix rather then some mystical imaginary number make much more sense to me. Complex number arithmetic would be just some "degenerated" subset, a convenient tool.