# Usage of Schrödinger equation vs Madelung equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

It is well known that [Madelung formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations) is alternative to the [Schrödinger Formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), cf. this previous [Madelung transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/madelung-transformation) Phys.SE post. I wanted to know what makes Schrödinger's formulation superior to that of Madelung, and in particular, when does the Madelung formulation fail?

Comment: And why do you think there are some superiority? I think they have same relation to Schrodinger as Euler equations to Newtons one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a translation from the German Wikipedia entry about the Madelung equations:

> Due to their non-linearity, the Madelung-equations are difficult to use in practise. However, they show that there exist non-linear equations that are based on linear equations.

Hope this helps.